# Trying to isolate a GPS conversion

Tags: gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

G'Day

I came across an application that is converting GPS co-ords to something else.
I am tryng to figure out what the format is.
Enter the standard

-26.61722 152.96033

and it stores this in the database

-15732970  91615170

Any ideas what the second pair are?
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be nearly impossible to answer, mainly because there are literally hundreds of different standards for storing point data. They all have different units of measurement and have differing levels of accuracy. Some take into account the curvature of an object, such as the earth, and others are simply distances from a point in a 2 dimensional plane.

This is of course assuming that the data stored is actually a different standard and not just a custom encoding of the numbers provided.

Perhaps the name of the application and vendor might help.